# "Sometimes...others" or "sometimes...in others"?

Tags: grammar

What's grammatically correct?

> Sometimes she used metaphors, others symbols and riddles.

or

> Sometimes she used metaphors, in others symbols and riddles.

What I'm trying here is to omit the word ***times***.

Comment: I would omit *sometimes* and say: At times she used metaphors, while in others symbols and riddles. (But I'm not a writer, I'm sure someone will come up with something better.)

Comment: I'd set the elliptical second sentence off with a semicolon: 'Sometimes she used metaphors; at other times, symbols and riddles.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  That's a bit of a tongue twister. I wouldn't pull off: "I'd set the elliptical second sentence off with a semicolon" after two or three glasses of Montepulciano, or even cheap trattoria wine!

Comment: Omitting the word "times" seems to give the sentence a very awkward structure. I concur with mplungjan's answer below, and think that you're only making things worse by getting rid of "times." Tongue-twisting aside, I like @Edwin's suggestion, too. Looking at your first sentence, I'd assume it was a typo, and that you had meant to say: _Sometimes she used metaphors, other symbols and riddles._ Why bother with _other_ at all? How about: _Sometimes she used metaphors, or symbols and riddles_.

Comment: *Sometimes she used metaphors, or symbols and riddles.* Isn't the same thing, again :) Think about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither is correct in my opinion.

It is generally used as

> *sometimes this; at other times that*

or

> *sometimes this, sometimes that*

Comment: *Sometimes* is not quite the same as *(at) some times*.

Comment: @TimLymington I do not quite get what you mean.

Comment: *Sometimes* can be replaced by *occasionally*; either would have to be followed by *at other times..*, not ? *others...*. On the other hand, *Some times are good, others bad* and **possibly** *Some times I win, others I lose*, depending on context.

Comment: That will take some people some time to get ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes she used metaphors, <strike>in</strike> **at** others, symbols and riddles.

Note also the comma after *others*.

Comment: No. It doesn't work to assume that _sometimes_ = _some times_ and omit the _times_ in the second half. It's just about understandable, but reads very oddly.

Comment: *Sometimes the crowd is the madness - at others it's the absence of the crowd that is.* (Will Self) http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/w/willself533504.html ; *Metropolitan Opera's new 'Eugene Onegin' sometimes soars but at others falters* ; *Lulu Cafe Patisserie: sometimes great but disappointing at others* ; *A Dangerous Method — Sometimes a Cigar is a Cigar; At Others It's a Giant Riding Crop.*

Comment: *Sometimes i reap, at others i sow* (Will Munter) ; *The band's voices sometimes come together in rich harmonies and at others fracture* ; *Sometimes he comes uninvited, but at others I think he's rather happy to be beckoned to (or even summoned)* ; *to keep their hearts open sometimes, but closed at others* ; *Sometimes it's rewarding – at others just exhausting.*

Comment: *... the literal geography of the "flowery" island of Anthemoessa, or Anthemusa, is fixed: sometimes on Cape Pelorum and at others in the islands known as the Sirenuse, near Paestum, or in Capreae* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siren) -- @ColinFine + 1 Up voter: There it is.

Comment: +1 for sheer determination and research, but why did you add a comma after "at others," when in none of your quoted examples there is one?

Comment: @Kris: OK, people use it. I still find it reads oddly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA To avoid ambiguity because rather than a single item after *at others*, there's now a list (could be a whole clause even).

Comment: @ColinFine Retracting the comment would have sufficed.